# How to get the latest version of google Chrome in specific month in the past?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I need to know which was the latest version of Chrome in specific month in the past three months (e.g. April 2019). How can I identify the latest version of specific month in the past?

Comment: I'm supposing you mean what version of chrome was used on your own machine,  not what version of chrome was used to access your website at that time?

Comment: I mean the latest stable version released by Google Chrome in that month which is supposedly what I was using (as Chrome perform automatic update when the user opens the browser).

Comment: Are you trying to get to a specific major version, or more detailed than that? With how quickly Chrome updates, you're not going to find anything much more specific than the major version tied to a specific month.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/) link. You can find there all update new of google chrome and you can choose year and month in the right side dropdown menu in case you need specific data for each month.